# Fullcalendar V4 get initialised calendar by documentId

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

We have a page that can contain multiple **full calendar** instances.

I allow the user to choose their theme and view and various other options dynamically.

In **V3** we used to:

1. **Destroy** the calendar based on the element id
2. **re-initialize** with the new options.

We were easily able to pass an **element Id** and destroy it by:

```
$("#someId").fullCalendar(‘destroy’)
```

In **V4** we can't just pass the element Id any longer. Looks like we would need to create a global variable to hold each calendar.

Is there a  way to get the **initialized calendar** based on the **element Id**?

Comment: the calendar is no longer a jQuery plugin, so yeah it's not attached to a jQuery object any more. It's just a general object. So you'd have to create a variable to hold a reference to your calendar, yes. But if you think about it, previously you could have done `var calendarEl = $("#someId");` as a global, and then called methods on that repeatedly, instead of creating a new jQuery object every time (which is wasteful). So it's not totally different. But yeah I think you can't just keep the element ID anymore, you have to keep a reference to the calendar object instead, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per  [V4 Destroy documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/destroy),

You can use destroy() method on calendar object.

Below is an example,

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendars = {};

  create_calendar('calendar'); // creates calendar for element with id 'calendar'
  create_calendar('calendar2'); // creates calendar for element with id 'calendar2'
  destroy_calendar('calendar'); // destroys calendar for element with id 'calendar'

  // function to destroy calendar that take element id as an argument

  function destroy_calendar(id) {
    calendars[id].destroy();
    delete calendars[id];
    console.log('calendar with id = "'+id+'" has been destroyed');
  }

  // function to create calendar that take element id as an argument

  function create_calendar(id) {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById(id);

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid'],
      defaultDate: '2019-03-12',
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    });
    calendars[id] = calendar;
    calendar.render();
    console.log('calendar with id = "'+id+'" has been created');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar,
#calendar2 {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.0.0-beta.4/core/main.css" integrity="sha512-SFYZeFgRSEZ2OUutPFk0nVSJ93GEoVIWWEA1cTpZ67b5lhYaYwwDZ9SeG5lNysgPJNwagcHBoegIqq+kwuo2LQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.0.0-beta.4/daygrid/main.css" integrity="sha512-PnqqvEx9xoUCNT0s0SJVwMfHA52MlX547UtDDL6h+3N4kz42EJsUOfM2+91lQ3w3Dr9THlb2nh3fmSO9/5VnzQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.0.0-beta.4/core/main.js" integrity="sha512-5LobOLPA5eTCr4M87YZjBSrSZUry3Ckvbbj7KA9/E8kFZq3Xq5OW+KfDBNCXjwG2T8QD6A745H3MWr2NqP2Log==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.0.0-beta.4/interaction/main.js" integrity="sha512-d7x1RUJWKezu09fJRRHhsX58Y7h+oM2vgIOswR25MA7tqthlh/cCv6ZeBY29NlLN+pJ5X85ujAr1VHVB8LaK+A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.0.0-beta.4/daygrid/main.js" integrity="sha512-XbJEgFuW5EDNC7q8XSEL554VgleQOQlUEt2gJXNp22PKk7+r9f7ki+o9pd7ygwV6LH/SMemodLNZ+4D1ABlgrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
<div id='calendar2'></div>
```

Comment: The question was: Is there a way to get the initialized calendar based on the element Id? The key part is to get the inialized calendar not re-initialise it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this this out.  I know JQuery isn't the cool kid on the block any more, but it still has its uses:

```
<script>
    // Globally setup your calendar by initializing it
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var myCalendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
    });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        // Any changes to the calendar before it renders the first time
    });

    // Any JQuery event can then access the initialized object
    $(".calendarSource").click(function () {
        console.log(myCalendar.getDate());
    });
<script>
```